# What is actually the speed reported by dd?

Tags: performance, dd, benchmark

I always thought that when doing:

```
dd if=/dev/sdx of=/dev/sdy
```

the report which is displayed once the command finishes, such as:

```
79304319+0 records in
79304319+0 records out
40603811328 bytes (41 GB) copied, 459.645 s, 88.3 MB/s
```

contains the speed which corresponds to the slowest one between:

- The read speed from the input,
- The write speed to the output,
- What happens between the read and the write,

that is if I'm copying data from an USB drive which have a read speed of 5 MB/s to an SSD, `dd` will actually report 5 MB/s, independently of the speed of the SSD.

In practice, I was copying a disk connected to USB 2 (checked it twice, the manual says it's USB 2.0 and even precises the connection speed of 480 Mbps), and noticed that `dd` reports the speed which varies from 65 to 88 MB/s, that is higher than [the maximum  speed of 60 MB/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_2.0) for USB 2.0.

What is happening there?

Is the speed shown by `dd` the addition of the read speed and write speed (which would mean that the actual speed is approximately 40 MB/s, which makes more sense)?

---

Additional information: I was doing a copy of a hard disk which presents an increasing number of bad sectors in order to have a clone I can experiment with. After copying the whole disk, the reported speed is indeed higher than expected:

```
3902854784+0 records in
3902854784+0 records out
1998261649408 bytes (2.0 TB) copied, 26040.5 s, 76.7 MB/s
```

given that the command was repeated for the first few (2 to 3) gigabytes only. I checked and rechecked, the copied disk is the correct one and the motherboard has no support for USB 3 (and there are no additional PCI-e cards for USB 3).

`hdparm`'s results are even stranger:

```
$ hdparm -tT /dev/md0

/dev/md0:
 Timing cached reads:   13498 MB in  2.00 seconds = 6755.77 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 486 MB in  3.00 seconds = 161.77 MB/sec

$ hdparm -tT /dev/md0

/dev/md0:
 Timing cached reads:   15058 MB in  2.00 seconds = 7536.75 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 418 MB in  3.01 seconds = 138.91 MB/sec

$ hdparm -tT /dev/md0

/dev/md0:
 Timing cached reads:   15038 MB in  2.00 seconds = 7527.54 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 386 MB in  3.01 seconds = 128.38 MB/sec
```

Comment: Although I don't know the reason for your results, dd's reporting how many bytes per second it can transfer from point A to point B. Adding read/write speeds would be incredibly counter-intuitive. I know of no utility which does that.

Comment: `/dev/md0` is a raid array, not your usb drive.

Comment: Can you run `iostat 5` (iostat is part of the `sysstat` package if you don't have it installed yet) during a disk copy and see whether the read and write numbers for those two disks are close to what dd is reporting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general `dd` displays the time it took for the entire transfer and the speed is "amount of data divided by time it took". Basically it's the same you should get with `time dd ...`, no magic there.

```
40603811328 bytes (41 GB) copied, 459.645 s, 88.3 MB/s
40603811328 / 459.645 / 1000 / 1000 = 88.3373
```

Maybe you cancelled the dd at some point and restarted it, whereupon a substantial portion of the data was already cached and thus the cache is messing with your statistics? You can try `hdparm -tT /dev/disk` to get a rough estimate of actual drive speeds.

For USB2 the speed is indeed highly suspect, I hope you did not use the wrong devices by accident.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, I cancelled `dd` and restarted it several times after it copied the first few gigabytes, but the speed is still the same for the whole disk. I checked once more, the disk is the right one and the motherboard doesn't have USB 3 support.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you specify `oflag=direct` or `conv=fsync`, then the kernel buffers the data and so `dd` thinks it is done as soon as the kernel has accepted the last of the data, which may be a few seconds before it makes it to the drive.  For small amounts of data, that can introduce significant error to the throughput estimate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It appears that the speed is still strange when copying the whole disk (2 TB), not just for small amounts of data.